Setting up Local Environment for Angular Tutorial
I'm learning Angular, trying to complete the "Your first Angular app" tutorial on angular.dev: https://angular.dev/tutorials/first-app/01-hello-world.
The tutorial gives you a .zip download with the source code so you can follow along in your local environment. However, the .zip file contains only a single folder, the src folder. There is no package.json, and no other configuration files. The tutorial instructs you to run npm install but doing so yields npm ERR! code ENOENT due to there being no package.json file. Am I missing something? What steps can I take to run the source code for this tutorial in my local environment?

Hard to say what you downloaded, but my copy has more than just src/ in.

Better to start with ng new... see this one: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt0#create-a-new-workspace-and-an-initial-application

Ok so my confusion was due to the fact that the text of the tutorial instructs you to download the source code by clicking on the "download" icon in the top right of the website's code editor. Doing this, at least for me, yielded a .zip which only contained the source folder. If you watch the video, however, they give you a Github link which contains all of the relevant configuration files.
